# OpenJPA: Exclude field update from an optimistic lock

Tags: java, openjpa

I'm using optimistic locking in my persistence context and trying to figure out a way to avoid write locking entity by updates to some entity fields.

Here's an example:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    @Version
    private long version;
}
```

So what I need is to avoid write locks (i.e. increment of a `version` field at the end of transaction) to the entity when updating `field2`, but still to have the default behavior on updates of any other entity field.

The solution I've figured out so far is to create my own versioning strategy (extend `NumberVersionStrategy` in case of example) to avoid incrementing entity's version if *only* specified fields were updated (only `field2` in the example above). But this solution looks quite complex to me... Isn't there a special annotation for a field to exclude it from entity versioning or something? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a OpenJPA feature that allows you to exclude a given field from optimistic locking.